# how to save entity with relationship in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have a spring boot application where I want to send an json object with a relationship. I have one entity called meetingSetting and one called meetingTime. MeetingSetting can have as many meetingTimes as possible and one meetingTime object belongs to one meetingSetting. But when I try to send it I am getting the following error:

```
not-null property references a null or transient value : com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime.meetingsSetting
```

I tried debugging and noticed that meetingSetting is empty when it is sent inside the times object send in the json. Could someone look at my code and tell me what I am missing, my guess is that I have to extend my saveMethod in meetingSettings but it is just a guess.

here is my MeetingSetting entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_settings")
@Data    
public class MeetingsSetting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name")
    private String meetingName;

    @Column(name = "meeting_url")
    private String meetingUrl;

    @Column(name = "meeting_pw")
    private String meetingPw;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingsSetting", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();            
}
```

meetingTime entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Data
public class MeetingTime {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_settings_name", nullable = false)
    private MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting;
}
```

MeetingSettingCOntroller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/meetingSetting")
public class MeetingSettingController {

    @Autowired
    MeetingSettingService meetingSettingService;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void saveMeeting(@RequestBody MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting){
        meetingSettingService.saveMeeting(meetingsSetting);

    }
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class MeetingSettingService {


    @Autowired
    MeetingSettingRepository meetingSettingRepository;


    public void saveMeeting(@RequestBody MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting){
        meetingSettingRepository.save(meetingsSetting);
    }
```

Update new code:

MeetingTime:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Data
public class MeetingTime {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name", nullable = false)
    private MeetingsSetting meetingName;
}
```

MeetingSettings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_settings")
@Data

public class MeetingsSetting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name")
    private String meetingName;

    @Column(name = "meeting_url")
    private String meetingUrl;

    @Column(name = "meeting_pw")
    private String meetingPw;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingName", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Sql script:

```
create table meeting_times
(
    id                  bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    meeting_date        varchar(255) null,
    start_time          varchar(255) null,
    end_time            varchar(255) null,
    meeting_name varchar(255)       null,
    constraint fk_meeting_times__meeting_settings_name
        foreign key (meeting_name) references meeting_settings (meeting_name)
);
```

Comment: How is the meeting_settings table linked to the meeting_times table? Like, is their a foreign key relation? Usually in @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingsSetting", cascade = CascadeType.ALL), the mappedBy is set to the field in which the foreignKey is on. 
@JoinColumn(name = "meeting_settings_name", nullable = false) is also a bit off, since this is saying that this entity is joined via a field called "meeting_settings_name" but MeetingTime doesn't have a column called meeting_settings_name to do the join on and the field on meetingSettings is called "meeting_name" not "meeting_settings_name"

Comment: You also don't need the @RequestBody on the service method. That's only used in your controller when going from the service calls to the actual java app.

Comment: meeting_settings_name is a foreign key on the meeting_times table

Comment: this is the script with which I generate my table for meeting_times, do I still have to reference meeting_names?create table meeting_times
(
    id                  bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    meeting_date        varchar(255) null,
    start_time          varchar(255) null,
    end_time            varchar(255) null,
    meeting_settings_id bigint       null,
    constraint fk_meeting_times__meeting_settings_name
        foreign key (meeting_settings_name) references meeting_settings (meeting_name)
);

Comment: ahhhh, I see!!!! your foreign key is meeting_settings_id on on meetings_times not the meeting_name.

Comment: no just edited it was my mistake I had posted a wrong version. Now the foreign key is meeting_settings_name referencing meeting_name in the other table. But I am trying your advice in the other post right now

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a null issue is that on `@JoinColumn(name = "meeting_settings_name", nullable = false)` you've got `nullable = false`. the column you're joining on is `meeting_settings_name` which doesn't seem to be a column on `meeting_times` and the actual name on `meeting_settings` is `meeting_name`. You'll have to add `meeting_name` to `meeting_times` to create a relation between the two tables to get this to work.

Comment: meeting_settings_name is existing in meeting_times table. I did not understand what you mean with the second one? I mean this part: "the column you're joining on is meeting_settings_name which doesn't seem to be a column on meeting_times and the actual name on meeting_settings is meeting_name. You'll have to add meeting_name to meeting_times to create a relation between the two tables to get this to work." sorry not a native english speaking

Comment: No worries! Yeah, so in your MeetingsSetting class you've got 
@Column(name = "meeting_name")
    private String meetingName;
which tells me the column in your database is "meeting_name" on your "meeting_settings" table. If you want to join to "meeting_times" on this, the "meeting_times" table needs a "meeting_name" column, which should be on your "meeting_times" entity. This would also mean that  @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_settings_name", nullable = false) is wrong since you're actually joining on the column "meeting_name". Does that help?

Comment: hi after changing my script to meeting_names I am getting this error: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime.meeting_setting in com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.meetinsSetting.MeetingsSetting.meetingTime
I will show you the updated code now

Comment: I put the changes as far as I understood under updated code in my orignal post

Comment: So I believe this is still a problem with the  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingsSetting", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) on the MeetingSettings entity. You need to tell the OneToMany what field you are using to map these objects. You're going to have to add the meetingName field to both the meetingSetting and meetingTime entities and then change mappedBy = meetingName

Comment: Because the meetingName field on the entities is what it's mapping the two things together by.

Comment: So add 
 @Column(name = "meeting_name")
    private String meetingName;
To both entities, then just change mappedBy to be meetingName

Comment: I just updated my code again can you take a look? I changed meetingSettings mapped by too and meetingTimes to it has joinColum instead of column is that fine? It still does not work the same error....

Comment: You still need to change 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingsSetting", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
on the MeetingSetting to be mappedBy = "meetingName"

Comment: I did look at the code under "Updated code" there it says mappedBy = meetingName or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: oop, sorry yeah that was my bad I was looking at the wrong block of code. It does seem though that you're still missing 
@Column(name = "meeting_name")
    private String meetingName;
in the updated MeetingTime entity. You need both entities to have the field you're mappingBy on them.

Comment: I just did it but got this error when I tried starting the application: 
Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime column: meeting_name (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: try adding , insertable=false, updatable=false to the @JoinColumn annotation. This just limits MeetingTime from updating MeetingSetting which should be updated through the MeetingSetting parent object.

Comment: I just did it worked but now I am getting this error haha the errors wont stop: Referencing column 'meeting_name' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'FK1omm6fk51xdsd0kysqbmleweg' are incompatible. THe thing is I am nowwhere referencing id

Comment: One step forward though! This one I probably can't really help with. It sounds like there's a foreign key that refers to the id field instead of the meeting_name field, but I'm not sure where that could be.

Comment: yeah you are right. Thanks for the amazing help :) I will try to fix that error now